# How do I can record incoming and outcoming calls in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, voice-recording

Who knows how to record incoming and outcoming calls in Windows Mobile SDK C#?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not really the reply you want but here is some information.

This has been discussed a lot on the MSDN-forums, for instance 
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/f3a3c50b-79cc-40d6-bb75-548b3700181c/) and here [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/65897b3b-da11-458b-b191-b9e4f6825843/). They say it's tricky, mostly due to hardware-restrictions, but I believe they don't like to discuss it because recording phone-calls is not legal in all countries/states.

Some people have been writing software and recorded phone-calls by using the microphone and the speaker but normally the result isn't that good. However, there is a developer over at [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) (where else) who has managed to use the built-in soundcard to record conversations. Have a look at this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=536472) at XDA.

He said that he used OpenNetCF so maybe the SO-user **ctacke** can give some more information.

As said, probably not the kind of reply you wanted but maybe you found it useful.

Good luck!

BTW, if you find out how, please share!